Keep message boxes on top an in active screen
I have a script which, at its start, creates several dialog boxes to ask for input data. First a message appears "Select target folder". After clicking, a folder browser appears to allow the user to select the folder. Then another message box with "select source file" appears, after clicking it a file browser appears to select a source file. Lastly, message box with "select a template" appears and after clicking file browser appears to allow user to select a template which will be used during the script execution.
Problem is, that the dialogs behave erratically. Most of the time the message boxes appear in the background, which is rather confusing since the user likely does not notice it. Another problem is, that when the script is run on a computer with two connected displays, message boxes appear on one display, browsers on the other. And the most confusing thing is that all of that is MOSTLY, not always. Sometimes the message boxes appear on the top (most frequently the first one). Here's the relevant code:
function Show-MessageBox {
    param (
        [string]$message
    )
    [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show($message, "Information", [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxButtons]::OK, [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxIcon]::Information)
}

function Select-FolderDialog {
    $folderBrowser = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.FolderBrowserDialog
    $folderBrowser.Description = "Select the target folder"
    $folderBrowser.ShowNewFolderButton = $true

    if ($folderBrowser.ShowDialog() -eq [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::OK) {
        return $folderBrowser.SelectedPath
    } else {
        Write-Host "Folder selection canceled."
        exit
    }
}

function Select-FileDialog {
    $fileBrowser = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog
    $fileBrowser.Filter = "Excel Files|*.xlsx"
    $fileBrowser.Title = "Select a file"

    if ($fileBrowser.ShowDialog() -eq [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::OK) {
        return $fileBrowser.FileName
    } else {
        Write-Host "File selection canceled."
        exit
    }
}

# Display messages and prompt for input using dialogs
Show-MessageBox -message "Vyber cílovou složku."
$targetFolder = Select-FolderDialog

Show-MessageBox -message "Vyber zdrojový soubor"
$dataFilePath = Select-FileDialog

Show-MessageBox -message "Vyber šablonu"
$templateFilePath = Select-FileDialog

How do I keep all the six windows on one screen (preferably the one on which the script was run) and on top so that I don't have to switch to them every time?

Why do you add more message box(es) leading to an extra click(s) (which must be annoying for any user)?
Just specify sufficient info to each productive dialogue, e.g. as follows:
if ( -not ("System.Windows.Forms.FolderBrowserDialog" -as [type]) ) {
    Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
}

function Select-FolderDialog {
    param(
        $Description = "Select the target folder"
    )
    $folderBrowser = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.FolderBrowserDialog
    $folderBrowser.Description = $Description
    $folderBrowser.ShowNewFolderButton = $true
    if ($folderBrowser.ShowDialog() -eq [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::OK) {
        return $folderBrowser.SelectedPath
    } else {
        Write-Host "Folder selection canceled."
        exit
    }
}

function Select-FileDialog {
    param(
        $Description = "Select a file"
    )
    $fileBrowser = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog
    $fileBrowser.Filter = "Excel Files|*.xlsx"
    $fileBrowser.Title = $Description
    if ($fileBrowser.ShowDialog() -eq [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::OK) {
        return $fileBrowser.FileName
    } else {
        Write-Host "File selection canceled."
        exit
    }
}

$targetFolder = Select-FolderDialog -Description "Vyber cílovou složku."

$dataFilePath = Select-FileDialog -Description "Vyber zdrojový soubor"

$templateFilePath = Select-FileDialog -Description "Vyber šablonu"


Create a form and run everting from the form,
You can customize the form to your liking.
function Show-MessageBox {
    param (
        [string]$message
    )
    [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show($message, "Information", [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxButtons]::OK, [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxIcon]::Information)
}

function Select-FolderDialog {
    $folderBrowser = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.FolderBrowserDialog
    $folderBrowser.Description = "Select the target folder"
    $folderBrowser.ShowNewFolderButton = $true

    if ($folderBrowser.ShowDialog() -eq [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::OK) {
        return $folderBrowser.SelectedPath
    } else {
        Write-Host "Folder selection canceled."
        Write-Error 'Stop' -ErrorAction Stop 

    }
}

function Select-FileDialog {
    $fileBrowser = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog
    $fileBrowser.Filter = "Excel Files|*.xlsx"
    $fileBrowser.Title = "Select a file"

    if ($fileBrowser.ShowDialog() -eq [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::OK) {
        return $fileBrowser.FileName
    } else {
        Write-Host "File selection canceled."
        Write-Error 'Stop' -ErrorAction Stop
    }
}
$form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$form.StartPosition = "CenterScreen"


$form.Add_Shown({

        # Display messages and prompt for input using dialogs

        Show-MessageBox -message "Vyber cílovou složku."
        try { $targetFolder = Select-FolderDialog } catch { $form.Close() ; return}

        Show-MessageBox -message "Vyber zdrojový soubor"
        try { $dataFilePath = Select-FileDialog } catch { $form.Close() ; return}
        
        Show-MessageBox -message "Vyber šablonu"
        try { $templateFilePath = Select-FileDialog } catch { $form.Close() ; return} 

})

$form.ShowDialog()


